# Dropdown does not select data flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dropdown

Someone can explain me why i can't select another item in my dropdown please. When i click, dropdown button reset. I get no errors, so i don't know where the problem comes from.

I have followed the flutter documentation but always same error.

```
  Widget dropdown(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference sneakers =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("sneakers");

    final _raffle = TextEditingController();

    String dropdownValue;
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: _raffle,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter some text';
            }
            return null;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "raffles",
          ),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: sneakers.snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }

            return new DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 24,
              elevation: 16,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue;
                  print(newValue);
                });
              },
              items: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: doc.reference.id.toString(),
                    child: Text(
                      doc['name'],
                    ));
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Code shown is not enough, but I guess you are initializing the variable dropdownValue in the build function, hence, it resets on setState.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSherif sorry i have updated my post

Comment: it works ty very much @AbdelrahmanSherif

Comment: You're very welcome :) Best of luck!